# JS: Почему return возвращает undefined?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите почему return возвращает undefined в функции nth, когда строкой выше в консоль выводится верное значение? Строки 32, 33. Код: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x07a7p67/2/)

```js
function arrayToList(arr) {
    list = null;
    arr = arr.reverse();
    for (i=0; i< arr.length; i++) {
      list = prepend(arr[i], list)
    }
    return list;
}

function prepend(element,list) {
    newlist = {
       value: element,
        rest: list
    }
    return newlist;
}

function listToArray(list) {
    arr = [];
    do {
       arr.push(list.value);
        if (list.rest)
         list = list.rest;
        else
         list = null;
    } while(list)
    return arr;
}

function nth(list, position){
    if (position == 0){
           console.log(list.value);  
           return list.value;
    } else if (position > 0) {
       position--;
       if (list.rest) {
           list = list.rest;         
           nth(list, position); 
       } else {
           return undefined;
       }
    } 
}

var arrayValue = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
arrayToList(arrayValue);
console.log(listToArray(arrayToList([10, 20, 30])));
console.log(nth(arrayToList([10, 20, 30]), 1));
```

Делал по заданию:

> Напишите функцию arrayToList, которая строит такую структуру, получая
> в качестве аргумента [1, 2, 3], а также функцию listToArray, которая
> создаёт массив из списка. Также напишите вспомогательную функцию
> prepend, которая получает элемент и создаёт новый список, где этот
> элемент добавлен спереди к первоначальному списку, и функцию nth,
> которая в качестве аргументов принимает список и число, а возвращает
> элемент на заданной позиции в списке, или же undefined в случае
> отсутствия такого элемента.
> Если ваша версия nth не рекурсивна, тогда напишите её рекурсивную версию.

Comment: `undefined` возвращается когда `position > 0`. В ветке `if (list.rest)` у вас отсутствует `return nth(list, position);`

Comment: И jsfiddle был нужен на ХК, здесь есть свой "мини-jsfiddle` - при создании/редактирования вопроса/ответа в менюшке сверху листок со стрелками (фрагмент кода - Control M). Не полная замена фидлу, но для простых вопросов хватит за глаза. Да и если не хватает функциональности (например, dojo используется), можно сюда вставить для истории и в jsfiddle для рабочего примера

Comment: Спасибо, действительно не дописал return  перед nth(list, position); Напишите пожалуйста ответом чтобы я смог подтвердить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того, чтобы функция всегда возвращала необходимое значение (число, строку, или тот же `undefined`) необходимо чтобы необходимое значение возвращалось при проходе каждой ветки условия, либо чтобы это значение возвращалось где-то вне условий.

Кроме того, я смотрю на ваш код и вижу, что для `position < 0` ничего не возвращается. Если уж вы рассматриваете все ветки условий, то было бы не плохо обрабатывать явно и такие условия, чтобы было видно - условие не забыто (либо указывать это в комментарии).

В вашем случае в условии `if (list.rest) {...}` ничего не возвращается. Это равносильно `return undefined;` в конце функции.

Соответственно, для того, чтобы исправить вашу ошибку необходимо исправить ваш код, например, так:

```
function nth(list, position){
    if (position == 0) {
        console.log(list.value);  
        return list.value;
    } else if (position > 0) {
        position--;
        if (list.rest) {
            list = list.rest;         
            return nth(list, position); 
        } else {
            return undefined;
        }
    } 
    return undefined;
}
```

Но куча условий (тем более вложенных) затрудняет чтение программы (возможно потому вы и пропустили нужный `return`). Поэтому неплохо было бы переписать вашу функцию. Я бы сделал это, например, так:

```
function nth(list, position){
    if (position == 0) {
        console.log(list.value);  
        return list.value;
    }
    if (position < 0 || !list.rest) {
        return undefined;
    }
    position--;
    list = list.rest;         
    return nth(list, position); 
}
```

По тому как оформлять условия (очередность проверок, использований функций для самих проверок и т.д.) существует куча различных мнений, но это отдельная история