# return возвращает undefined в рекурсивной функции

Tags: javascript

Пытаюсь написать простую рекурсивную функцию, но return возвращает undefined, не смотря на то, что console.log() выводит всё правильно. Возможно стоило поместить return в другое место, но в таком случае функция зациклиться.

Вот мой код:

```
var sum = ""
function my_function(n) {
    sum += " " + n
    if (n == 1) {
        console.log(sum)
        return sum;
    }
    my_function(n-1);

}

console.log(my_function(9))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно добавить еще один `return` после вызова функции

```js
let sum = ""

function my_function(n) {

  sum += " " + n
  if (n == 1) {
    console.log(sum)
    return sum;
  }

  my_function(n - 1);
  return sum


}

console.log(my_function(9))
```

P.S: тут подробно описан [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416000/js-%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-return-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-undefined)